# Mixing rangeinput from jQuery Tools and draggable from jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-tools

I currently use the rangeinput plugin from jQuery Tools in various places. But I now have to implement some other functionality using draggable from jQuery UI and it turns out the draggables are not working when there's a rangeinput in the page, which in my case is inevitable.

I am willing to change any of the libraries, preferably jQuery Tools as the rangeinput is the only part of the library that I use. I know that UI has a slider widget, but it doesn't provide quite the same ease of use as the rangeinput from Tools.

Any suggestions what I should do?

I am using jQuery UI 1.8.9 (comes with Wordpress) and jQuery Tools 1.2.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have the right idea by replacing the jQuery Tools part of your code with something else.  jQuery Tools is terribly out of date (not updated since jQuery 1.4.2) and poorly supported in their own community.

Have you looked at these?

http://www.newmediacampaigns.com/files/posts/nmcdateranger/index.html

http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/update_jquery_ui_slider_from_a_select_element_now_with_aria_support/

http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/range.html

http://mypaaji.com/Index.php/price-slider-with-product-interface/

http://interface.eyecon.ro/demos/slider_minmax.html

Comment: No, I don't use it for dates. It's just a plain slider with min and max values, a minimal step and a field that shows the current number. Chrome and Firefox 4 have this natively (without the indicator, just the slider), but I need a consistent look in all browsers.

Comment: The second link then?   You can make it do whatever you need.  No matter which plugin you choose, you'll have to do some amount of configuration.

Comment: It's not as I'd like it to be, but I agree that this is the best solution so I'll accept your answer.